# ggplot subsetting in loop

Tags: r, ggplot2, subset, lapply

here is a problem I have with ggplot+ lapply+ subsetting problem

here a reproducible exemple

`````
stages=as.vector(c("1","2","3","1","1","1","1","1","1","2","2","2","2","2","3","3","3","3","3","3","3","3","3","3","3","1","1"))
x13=c(0.9, 0, 0, 0.692, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.53, 0.5,0,2,3,55,49,64,9,4,1,0,54,0)
y13=c(0.9, 0, 0, 0.692, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.53,0.9, 0, 0, 0.692, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.53)
countmatrix=cbind(x13,stages,y13)
countmatrix=as.data.frame(countmatrix)
p2=ggplot(data=countmatrix, aes(stages, fill = x13))+
  geom_bar(position="stack",  fill="gray34")+
  geom_bar(data=subset(countmatrix, x13!=0),  aes(fill=stages ))
p2 ````
`````

[image]
once I put it in function to replicate over many variable it seems to not work (the subsetting part at least seems to not work.
here is the code I used.

```
barplotseries <- function(x){
  y=as.name(x)
  ggplot(data=countmatrix, aes(stages, fill = y))+
    geom_bar(position="stack",  fill="gray34")+
    geom_bar(data=subset(countmatrix,y!=0),  aes(fill=stages ))
}
x=c("x13","y13")
p2=lapply(x, barplotseries)
do.call("grid.arrange", c(p2, ncol=2))
```

[image]
all want is to be able to make the same plot above on as many variables as possible.

please let me know you suggestions (should I use For?) I don't know how to use it.

thanks

Comment: Your reproducible example does not include *stages*.

Comment: Save the plot inside your function using a variable so you can access it outside the function.

Comment: Also, reproducible example as is does not render such a plot. Please be sure to re-run posted code in an empty R environment (i.e., no previous globalenv objects) to make sure all compiles and renders accordingly.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to copy the first line. the vector stages is in now.  it's reproducible now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along the lines to what @Parfait pointed out, not a good idea to call globalenv objects.

Your original function doesn't work because 1. it takes in a string and you pass it into aes in ggplot2, 2. when you subset on countmatrix, you are passing the string in again..

Make a few edits and below should work:

```
#keep the data.frame as factors and numeric
stages=as.vector(c("1","2","3","1","1","1","1","1","1","2","2","2","2","2","3","3","3","3","3","3","3","3","3","3","3","1","1"))
x13=c(0.9, 0, 0, 0.692, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.53, 0.5,0,2,3,55,49,64,9,4,1,0,54,0)
y13=c(0.9, 0, 0, 0.692, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.53,0.9, 0, 0, 0.692, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.53)
countmatrix=data.frame(x13,stages,y13)
```

your edited function

```
barplotseries <- function(y,DATA){
  DATA_subset = subset(DATA,DATA[,y]>0)      
  ggplot(data=DATA, aes_string(x="stages", fill = y))+
    geom_bar(position="stack",  fill="gray34")+
    geom_bar(data=DATA_subset,  aes(fill=stages ))
}
```

combining the plots

```
x=c("x13","y13")
p2=lapply(x,function(i)barplotseries(i,countmatrix))
do.call("grid.arrange", c(p2, ncol=2))
```

[image]

You can also do other types of subsetting, like the y column greater than some cutoff:

```
barplotseries <- function(y,DATA){
  DATA_subset = subset(DATA,DATA[,y]>mean(DATA[,y])-1.96*sd(DATA[,y]))
  ggplot(data=DATA, aes_string(x="stages", fill = y))+
    geom_bar(position="stack",  fill="gray34")+
    geom_bar(data=DATA_subset,  aes(fill=stages ))
}
```

Comment: Hey Man! thank you so Much. it worked flawlessly!!! thanks a lot!

Comment: what is your subsetting rule now? I hope it is not too complex =p

Comment: I want to remove the to bottom 5% of the values (through a Z scoore eliminatation) ```data=subset(DATA,DATA[,y]>(mean(y))-1.96*sd(y))```, but it doesn't work

Comment: if I put a value like  data=subset(DATA,DATA[,y]> 0 or 1 or 2. it works, but it I put a formula it doesn't (like (mean(y))-1.96*sd(y)))

Comment: you have to call DATA[,y] again, because y here is a character..

so do something like data=subset(DATA,DATA[,y]>(mean(DATA[,y]))-1.96*sd(DATA[,y]))

Comment: a bit ugly.. but yeah maybe you can define the dataset outside the plot function

Comment: Error in `[.data.frame`(DATA, , y) : undefined columns selected , I think it might not be wise to keep complicating the subsetting within the ggplot function, so, how do I do it outside of the function?

Comment: I can rewrite the code or write another answer.. but.. your data frame is a bit weird, x13 is a factor? are you sure

Comment: no, x13 and y13 are both numerical, only stages is a factor (x13 and y13 have to be numerical otherwise I can't calculate a mean or an sd)

Comment: ok i see now.. I think I understand your plot now. Yeah if u cbind x13 with stages, they become characters automatically.

Comment: oh, ok. I see, I have changed y13 and x13 to numeric while keeping the stage as factor. no Error, but it doesn't seem subset anything

Comment: no worries, see if it's ok now.. Hey I think it's weird. Your sd is too huge. mean - 1.96 sd is some negative number.. so it is the same as filtering for >=0 , this is not a normal distribution

Comment: I was expecting this problem due to the many zero value. I have change your code to subset according to Quantile position, and it worked flawless.  DATA_subset = subset(DATA,DATA[,y]>quantile(DATA[,y],0.1)) .... Man I don't know who you are, but you are Damn efficient! thanks so much for your help!